# Problem with 'window' trying to implement auth in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, auth0

I am following [this](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-gatsby-with-auth0/) guide on setting up auth0 in Gatsby. I find that if I clone their repo on github and build it, it builds with no errors. But for some reason in my code, following their guide and copy/pasting their code, I can run it in development but not build.

Their code contains the following line:

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"
```

which is supposed to be a check to prevent the following error:

```
WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

And yet I get that error anyway. I put some console.log statements above and below the line of code and the build does appear to be breaking on that line.

Also, if I change the line to

```
console.log("test0")
const isBrowser = false;
console.log("test1")
```

and then I run `gatsby clean` then `gatsby build`, the code still gives the above error, but without the 'test0' printing. If I run `gatsby build` a second time, no clean, then it gives 'test0' and then gives the above error. I'm not sure why if I've taken 'window' out of it, it is still giving that error.

I tried changing my version of gatsby to an earlier version, but that didn't work either. My version is 2.23.4, I tried 2.12.0 because it's the earliest version that is compatible with another plugin I am using (gatsby-transformer-remark).

I would greatly appreciate any advice, I'm not really sure what else I should try here.

I have the following added to the end of `gatsby-node.js`

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    /*
     * During the build step, `auth0-js` will break because it relies on
     * browser-specific APIs. Fortunately, we don’t need it during the build.
     * Using Webpack’s null loader, we’re able to effectively ignore `auth0-js`
     * during the build. (See `src/utils/auth.js` to see how we prevent this
     * from breaking the app.)
     */
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /auth0-js/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the `gatsby-config.js` so set a custom `onCreateWebpackConfig`?

Comment: I did add that in yes. I can paste it above